# Parallel using tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I am currently creating an engine that will spin 10 new threads up that will do diffrent work. But i have found that my solution dose not run in Parallel.

```
public async Task Start(Func<string, Task> action)
{
   for (var i = 1; i <= config.threads; i++)
    {
        consumers.Add(getActionTask(action));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(consumers);
}

private Task getActionTask(Func<string, Task> action)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // Do something that returns a string
        String data = "Some string here";
        await action(data);
    }
}
```

Lets say i run 2 threads, and based on data will the first thread do a `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));`
The second thread will print "Hello" on a loop.

It will never get the print loop before the Delay is over, what is wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Can you post the code with the delay and print statements? By the way, don't wrap the `await action(data)` in a call to Task.Run, not necessary. The method `getActionTask` should just return `action(data);`

Answer (score 0):

The `Task.WhenAll` doesn't say that the tasks will run in parallel. It creates a `Task` that would be completed once all the tasks you pass as an argument to the `WhenAll` method would be completed.

If you want your code to run in parallel, you should make use of the `Parallel` class `ForEach` method.

**Update**

One important note as Scott pointed out below in his comment is that the functions in the `Parallel` class do not work with async methods. If you want to use async methods with it you must use [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: One important thing to note, the functions in the `Parallel` class do not work with async methods. If you want to use async methods with it you must use [`TPL Dataflow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for noting this ! I will include it in my answer.